# jump-ahead clocks with Oracle timestamps on Java 10

Tags: java, sql, oracle, h2, java-time

We have an application that has unit tests using H2 and integration tests using Oracle 11. All tests were passing using Java 8. We have a `Foo` table that has a `created_at` timestamp using SQL DDL `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL`, which we use both on Oracle and on H2 in Oracle mode.

Creating a `Foo` is simple. We create a timestamp in Java:

```
final Instant createdAt = Instant.now();
```

Then we have SQL to insert a new `Foo` row into the table, using the timestamp and other things:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (uuid, name, created_at, bar_id)
  SELECT ?, ?, ?, id FROM Bar WHERE Bar.name = ?;
```

(We do the little `SELECT` trick to make sure there is a matching `Bar` which we look up by name, but that doesn't relate to the timestamp.)

Filling in the timestamp in the prepared statement is easy:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.from(createdAt));
```

One thing to be aware of is that when we put `Foo` in the database, we don't query the value again; we return a `Foo` object using the Java `Instant` passed to us, assuming that it's the same as in the database (because we just inserted it).

We have another query to read the value back from the database. During the query, we get the value from the result set like this:

```
return Timestamp.toInstant(resultSet.getTimestamp("created_at"));
```

Nothing mysterious, from what I can see.

We upgraded from Java 8 to Java 10. Suddenly our unit tests failed with H2. It would appear (unless I'm mistaken) that [Java now supports microsecond precision in `Instant`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730), but H2 must have been storing the values at millisecond precision, so our assertions wouldn't match what we got back; one would have `000` for microseconds. (See H2 [Issue #1178](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1178).) So we worked around that my truncating to milliseconds:

```
assertThat(retrievedFoo.getCreatedAt().truncatedTo(MILLIS),
    is(createdFoo.getCreatedAt().truncatedTo(MILLIS)));
```

With our unit tests working on H2, we ran the same tests as integration tests on Oracle:

```
Expected: is <2018-06-05T14:32:32.111Z>
     but: was <2018-06-05T14:32:32.112Z>
```

Wait, what? The timestamp on the foo we *retrieved* was one millisecond *later* than the creation time? How is that possible? We truncated to milliseconds. Even if the `Instant` on Java 10 has more precision than Oracle is storing, we dropped everything after the milliseconds. How is Oracle's timestamp storage getting *ahead* of the original timestamp `Instant`?

Comment: Does your application have a need to track time down to the millisecond? You might be seeing a rounding issue or some other floating point issue. You might also be seeing a difference in each database's datatype. How is the time being stored?

Comment: Before I just start "doing things" I want to understand "what is happening". I don't want to guess that something "might be rounding". The time is being stored in Java in an `Instant`, and in Oracle as a `timestamp`, as indicated in the code above.

Comment: In my experience, unless there is a real need to look at milliseconds (maybe a financial transaction application), then it creates more headaches than necessary to look past the second or maybe the 10th of a second.

Comment: If you are storing a timestamp type on two different systems, I believe that timestamp value, even though it's created at one time, may `INSERT` slightly differently based on the machine clock that each database is running on. Again, if you don't need this level of precision, it's much less trouble to ignore it and not worry about why this happens. Just know that extreme time ranges are impacted by the system they are used on.

Comment: "…not worry about why this happens." For better or for worse, I am not that person. haha I'm not just going to twist dials and move levers until things start working until I understand why. It's just not my nature. :)

Comment: Fair enough, and I agree with that mindset. Though I'm not suggesting just "twisting dials and moving levers". I'm saying that a timestamp at a micro-precision can behave differently when multiple systems are involved. There are other factors, like cpu clock, that can come into play. You aren't just passing a value around. You are inserting what appears to be the same value in two different systems. It's not infeasible that extreme time precision can result in slightly different values. So if you don't need to worry about it, don't waste the brain power.

Comment: I completely agree with the comment about micro-precision and system clocks, etc. That's why I'm truncating to milliseconds!! So… if we truncate the micro-precision part, how do we wind up with a time that is _ahead_ of the other? This would only be the case if Oracle stored a timestamp that somehow rounded _up_! Has anyone ever heard of such a situation? That's the question, and that's what's puzzling.

Comment: Interesting. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (even if only verifiable in one run out of three)? I also suspect that in the process of doing so you may yourself learn something about your problem.